# Doing something on the final result of a recursive function, whithin the same function

Tags: haskell, recursion

Easier to show than to explain. I have this tiny function to do base conversion from base 10:

```
demode 0 _ = [] 
demode n b = m:(demode d b)
 where (d, m) = divMod n b
```

So, if we want to see how we would write 28 in base 9, demode 28 9 = [1,3].
But, of course, we have then to invert the list so it looks like a 31. 
This could be easily made by making a function that calls 'demode' and then reverses it result, but with Haskell being so cool and all that there's probably a more elegant way of saying "in the end case (demode 0 _), append everything to a list and then reverse the list".

Note that base conversion is just an example I'm using to illustrate the question, the real question is how to apply a final transformation to the last result of a recursive function.

Comment: Not relevant to your question, but I think your `demode` is broken: what is `demode 9 9`?  (Corner cases like that make good test cases, btw.).

Comment: what about using an outer function that calls `demode` and returns the reversed result?

Comment: demode 9 9 = [0 , 1] -> 10, isn't it fine?


About the outer function: that I thought of and I mentioned it above. Sure it is easy and good enough for this case, but in some other cases it would have been useful. Also, it's never bad to improve your haskell grammar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope.  Your only hope is to use a helper function.  Note that Haskell *does* allow you to define functions in `where` clauses (at least for now), so that doesn't have to be a 'separate function' in the sense of a separate top-level definition.  You have basically two choices:

Add an accumulator and do whatever work you want to do in the end:

```
demode n b = w n [] where
    w 0 xn = reverse xn
    w n xn = w d (xn ++ [m]) where
        (d, m) = divMod n b
```

Hopefully you can follow how that would work, but note that, in this case, you are far better off saying

```
demode n b = w n [] where
    w 0 xn = xn
    w n xn = w d (m : xn) where
        (d, m) = divMod n b
```

which builds the list in reversed order and returns that.

Push the regular definition down to a helper function, and wrap that function in whatever work you want:

```
demode n b = reverse (w n) where
    w 0 = []
    w n = m : w d where
        (d, m) = divMod n b
```

(I've used the term `w` as a short-hand for 'worker' in all three examples).

Either case can generally benefit from learning to do your recursions using higher-order functions, instead.

In general, it's somewhat bad style in Haskell to try to do 'everything in one function'; Haskell style is built around dividing a problem into multiple parts, solving those with separate functions, and composing the resulting functions together; *especially* if those functions will be useful elsewhere as well (which happens more often than you might naively expect).

Comment: Thanks!
But what do you mean "Haskell does allow you to define functions in where clauses (at least for now)", are there plans to forbid them in the future or something? 
That scares me, I love the flexibility of where clauses, it makes everything much cleaner and easier.

Comment: @AsíMaullóJosetustra - Snarking about this: http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/simonpj/papers/constraints/let-gen.pdf , mostly.  Presumably if few enough people use helper functions in `where` clauses it will eventually be removed as well.

Comment: @jcast, when someone as skilled and experienced as Simon Peyton Jones says the type system is too complex to debug, it probably is. Let generalization is a freebie in HM, but in Glasgow Haskell, it's expensive and (since scoped type variables are available) not worth the price. Así, you needn't worry about functions in `where` clauses--they're here to stay.